# Test for Statistical Differences Among GLM Modeled Data

Tags: anova, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, group-differences, kruskal-wallis-test

I have three independent data groups - the groups are comprised of census tracts.  Each data point (tract) within each group has a modeled estimate of disease prevalence (% pop that is obese as an example) and each tract estimate has its own 95%CI.

I'm trying to see if the tract-level estimated % of obesity in one group is different than another group. Is it possible to do an ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis on these estimates and their confidence intervals? If I do ANOVA or KW on just the modeled estimates and no confidence intervals I'm underestimating the difference between groups. I figure I'm also introducing more error when there's already modelimg error from making the point estimates.

Is there a different more suitable test?

Thanks in advance.